# Limit of groups with Kazhdan property (T)

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G_1 \le G_2 \le \cdots $ be countable groups with Kazhdan property (T). Let $G = \bigcup_i G_i$. Does it necessarily follow that $G$ has (T)?

This seems false but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: Property T discrete groups are finitely generated.

Comment: For a specific example take the union of $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ over $n\ge 3$. The chain of standard inclusions $SL(n,\mathbb Z)\to SL(n+1,\mathbb Z)$ does not stabilize so the union isn't finitely generated.

Comment: Examples are abundant: they include all infinite countable locally finite groups.

Comment: @YCor is it as easy when each $G_i$ is taken to have properties FH or FW? Does $SL_{\infty}(Z)$ have property FW?

Comment: @jonan every countable group with Property FW is finitely generated